# Capturing Culture Specific Wonders

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Civilization 5 BNW brings culture specific wonders. I'm wondering if those wonders maintain their effects after being captured if you haven't unlocked that social policy branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a Wonder has been constructed by someone who has unlocked the right culture branch, its benefits are available to whoever owns that Wonder. If somebody builds Uffizi, and you capture the city that has it, then Uffizi - and all its benefits - are yours.